# Fill cell containing NaN with average of value before and after considering groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to fill missing values in a pandas dataframe with the average of the cells directly before and after the missing value considering that there are different IDs.

```
maskedid test  value
 1        A      4
 1        B      NaN
 1        C      5
 2        A      5
 2        B      NaN 
 2        B      2
```

expected DF

```
 maskedid test  value
 1        A      4
 1        B      4.5
 1        C      5
 2        A      5
 2        B      3.5
 2        B      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].interpolate()
```

And by group:

```
df['value'] = df.groupby('maskedid')['value'].apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
```

Comment: i have tried it out. it does not take into consideration that there are different IDs. i need a a way to group by and then ably the technique. the way i have tried didnt work and the output was missy :D

Comment: Then add a `groupby`, see updated answer. But in the provided example this shouldn't make a difference. Please update your question with a better example of this still doesn't solve your problem

Comment: you are totally correct regarding the above example . I have tried the updated answer and I got  " 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'interpolate'"